# “Comparison method violates its general contract!” : java 7 error with Date data

Tags: java

I have found this issue in multiple threads and tried suggested replies. But didn't get success.

My code is mentioned below:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(CustomObject o) {
    try {
        if (getOriginalActionDate() == null || o.getOriginalActionDate() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(
                getOriginalActionDate()).compareTo(
                new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(o
                        .getOriginalActionDate()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing here? Any pointer in this regard will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Gopal lal

Comment: Did you even bother to google that?

Comment: yes..I googled about it. But as I mentioned, I tried many options mentioned in different different thread, but didn't get success.

Answer (score 5):

When both `Date`s are `null`, you should return `0` instead of `-1`.

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

For the code posted, when Date in both the objects are `null`

```
x.compareTo(y) == y.compareTo(x) == -1
```

and this violates the contract.

To fix the method, change the `if` for null check to:

```
if (getOriginalActionDate() == null && o.getOriginalActionDate() == null) {
    return 0;
} else if (getOriginalActionDate() == null) {
    return -1;
} else if (o.getOriginalActionDate() == null) {
    return 1;
}
```

So if both are null, the return value would be 0 (equal), otherwise the `null` would be regard as the smaller object.

Comment: @juergen d That is another Dumb typo that I made this week, thanks.

Comment: What did you change? Just change -1 -> 0 isn't going to improve things, you need to do a check for both == null before the check that either == null and return 0 in that case.

Comment: I have added code like this: if (getOriginalActionDate() == null) {
    return 0;
   }
   if (o.getOriginalActionDate() == null) {
    return 0;
   }.                                          Is it ok? If not, can you give small example for what you have said.

Comment: Thanks. the code example really helps me. Everything is working fine now.